# Form value not reset in angular if using mask='+1 000 000'

Tags: angular

I am not able to reset form field after submit the form whereas if I remove mask="+1 000 000-0000" then we're able to reset form

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="mobile" formControlName="mobile" type="tel" placeholder="Please enter a vaild mobile number" (keyup)="showDefaultRelationMobileerror($event)"  [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" mask="+1 000 000-0000">
```

Comment: There is no need to user `ngModel` with `formControlName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `ngModel` along with `formControlName` has been deprecated as of Angular 6 (https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel). You can use one or the other.

To make use of Reactive forms in Angular, use `formControlName` and to use template-driven forms, you can use `ngModel`.

As for your mask `+1 000 000-0000`, `1` is not recognised as a default pattern by ngx-mask (See the default patterns here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask#then). You can instead set the `prefix` attribute

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="tel"
           class="form-control" 
           formControlName="mobile" 
           placeholder="Please enter a vaild mobile number" 
           (keyup)="showDefaultRelationMobileerror($event)"  
           [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" 
           prefix="+1"
           mask=" 000 000-0000"
    />
    <button (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

To reset the form value, use the `reset()` method from the formControl class in your component

```
    form: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            'mobile': new FormControl()
        });
    }

    resetForm() {
        this.form.get('mobile').reset()
    }
```